# Change Label Background Colour on Input Focus

Tags: jquery, html, css, forms

So, I'm trying to change the background colour of a table td element, which contains the label for an input item. The input item, itself, is located in the following td element in the row. I am trying to force this background colour change on the focus of the input item. Below is what I have coded, thus far. It is failing to work at this point.

```
$(".input_field").child("input").focus(function() {
    $(this).parent("td").sibling("td").css("background","#cf4f92");
});

<tr>
    <td class="label_name"><label for="email">Email</label></td>
    <td class="input_field"><input type="text" name="email" maxlength="28" /></td>
</tr>

td.label_name {
    background:#dc95ba;
    color:#fff;
    font-size:16px; font-weight:bold; line-height:16px;
    padding:2px;
    text-align:right; text-transform:uppercase;
}
td.label_name label {
    margin:0 10px;
    max-width:150px; width:auto;
}
td.input_field {
    margin:0; padding:0;
}
td.input_field input {
    border:1px solid #dc95ba;
    color:#e1a4c4;
    font-weight:bold;
    margin:0 0 0 -2px; padding:2px 2px 2px 10px;
    width:200px;
}
td.input_field input:focus {
    border:1px solid #cf4f92;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Solution here. http://jsfiddle.net/J9bWE/1/

I added a class on the tr.

```
<tr class="EntryRow">
    <td class="label_name"><label for="email">Email</label></td>
    <td class="input_field"><input type="text" name="email" maxlength="28" /></td>
</tr>
```

Take not how I called tr

```
$(".input_field input").focus(function() {
    $(this).closest(".EntryRow").find(".label_name").css("background","#cf4f92");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

try this. It works

```
$(".input_field > input").focus(function() {
    $(this).closest("tr").children("td:first").css("background","#cf4f92");
});​
```