# toggling styles on label when input field is focus with css only

Tags: css, input, styles, label

I need to toggle styles on the corresponding label when input's focus.
HTML+CSS:

```
<div>
<label for="e_mail">E-Mail</label>
<input type="text" />
</div>
input[type=text]:focus + label {
color: red;
}
```

P.S. how to do this without changing tags "label" and "input" in HTML?

Comment: You can´t do it in CSS, jQuery is your solution. In CSS  there is no "previous sibling" selector.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change Label Background Colour on Input Focus](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13907854/change-label-background-colour-on-input-focus)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only do that with pure CSS if `label` is inserted after the `input`. A fix to that could be using `float: left;` on the label to put it to the left.

Also, `<label for=""></label>` require the input to have a `id` in order to work propertly.

```
<div>
  <input type="text" id="e_mail" />
  <label for="e_mail">E-Mail</label>
</div>
```

-

```
input[type="text"]:focus + label {
  color: red;
}
label {
  float: left;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/vcw880fr/1/